# php curl_exec cannot get urlencoded link's content

Tags: php

The link is: [this](http://web.centanet.com/m/Property/%E6%B5%B7%E6%80%A1%E5%8D%8A%E5%B3%B64%E6%9C%9F%E5%BE%A1%E5%BA%AD%E5%9C%92%E5%BE%A1%E6%9E%97%E5%B1%85%2833%E5%BA%A7%29/TIB981-0813)

It is ok to open in my browser. However, when i use the following php script to get the content, it shows: Runtime Error. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$html = get_url_contents('http://web.centanet.com/m/Property/%E6%B5%B7%E6%80%A1%E5%8D%8A%E5%B3%B64%E6%9C%9F%E5%BE%A1%E5%BA%AD%E5%9C%92%E5%BE%A1%E6%9E%97%E5%B1%85%2833%E5%BA%A7%29/TIB981-0813');
echo $html;
exit;

function get_url_contents($url){
       $crl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
       $ret = curl_exec($crl);
       curl_close($crl);
       return $ret;
}
```

Comment: you can use `$crl = curl_init($url)` to save having to call the `curl_setopt()`

Answer (score 2):

No Problem, if you mean is " Object moved to here. " Message, Use from below code :

```
<?php
$html = get_url_contents('http://web.centanet.com/m/Property/%E6%B5%B7%E6%80%A1%E5%8D%8A%E5%B3%B64%E6%9C%9F%E5%BE%A1%E5%BA%AD%E5%9C%92%E5%BE%A1%E6%9E%97%E5%B1%85%2833%E5%BA%A7%29/TIB981-0813');
echo $html;
exit;

function get_url_contents($url)
{
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true ); //FOLLOW TO CHANGE LOCATION
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

?>

Comment: If your problem solved, please selected it for best answer . tnx

Comment: The problem is still occur, the error is: Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application.

Comment: Your web server limited probably, test it on local